# Need help comparing difference between datetime stamps in SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a MSSQL server 2012 express DB that logs user activities. I need some help creating a query to compare timestamps on the user activities based on the text in the notes.  I am interested in figuring out how long it takes my users to perform certain activities. The activities they are performing are stored in text in a NOTES column. I want to build a query that will tell me the time difference for each  [INVOICEID] from the ‘START NOTE’ to the next note for that invoice by that user. The note that is entered is always the same for the start of the timer (for the purposes of this I used ‘START NOTE’ to indicate the start of the timer, but I have multiple activites I will need to do this for so I plan on simply changing that text in the query), but the end of the timer the text of the note will vary because it will be user entered data. I want to find the time difference between ‘START NOTE’ and the note that immediately follows ‘START NOTE’ entered by the same USERID for the same INVOICEID. Please see the SQLfiddle for an example of my data:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a00d7/1

With the data in the sql fiddle I would want the results of this query to be:

```
INVOICE ID  USERID      TIME_Difference
100         5           1 day
101         5           3 days
102         5           9 days
```

(time_difference does not need to be formatted like that, standard SQL formatting is fine)

I don’t really know where to start with this. Please let me know if you can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with x as (
    select 
        o.*, sum(case when notes='START NOTE' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by o.invoiceid, o.userid order by o.added) as grp
    from om_note o
),
y as (
    select *,
            row_number() over(partition by x.invoiceid, x.userid, x.grp order by x.added) as rn
    from x
    where grp > 0
)
select y1.invoiceid, y1.userid, datediff(hour, y1.added, y2.added) 
from y y1
inner join y y2
on y1.invoiceid=y2.invoiceid and y1.userid=y2.userid and y1.grp=y2.grp
where y1.rn=1 and y2.rn=2
```

Comment: this one works perfect except but there is one minor bug, it works great when the order of the rows are perfect, but once the order of the rows is not exact it puts out strange results. please see the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59c01/1  all I did was change the location of the 2nd row of data to the end of the data set and it messes up the result for that set. (i also changed it to hours and added a few columns for testing) I am sure theres a simple fix but im not sure how to implement. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: wow, this one works perfect! I forgot about one minor thing as I was testing against real data. I can have the START NOTE occur many times on one InvoiceID and it can involve many different userID's. there is a repetitive process that gets done to a small set of invoices and it happens by any user. What will happen is user1 will put in the note 'START NOTE' then have an action, then user2 will come along and do the same thing. If possible Id like these to all be reported as separate line items in the result set, currently its only reporting the first one. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ee63/1

Comment: Updated again, hope we covered everything now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.userid,a.invoiceid,min(a.added),min(b.added),datediff(DAY,min(a.added),min(b.added)) from om_note a 
left join om_note b on a.userid=b.userid and a.invoiceid = b.invoiceid and a.added < b.added
where a.notes = 'START NOTE' group by a.userid,a.invoiceid
```